# Can logging to catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.out be disabled?

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat6

Using the default JULI logging, is it possible to keep logging to `catalina.out` but disable the daily catalina logs that are created like `catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.out`?

I can only find references to disabling catalina logging entirely or switching to log4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried commenting the appropiate FileHandlers in `tomcat/conf/logging.properties`?

So basically all lines required for you are:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

ps.: This will stop logging all logs in `tomcat/logs` except catalina.out and the access_log logfile.